# Как отключить 3d пространство?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Имеется такой код:

Можно ли отключить 3D пространство для синего блока? `.someinner`
Чтобы он был обычной плоской фигурой, или это не возможно?

```css
.wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
}

.some {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 10px solid red;
  transform: rotateX(50deg)
}

.someinner {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="some">
    <div class="someinner">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86522/discussion-on-question-by-uzi-no-uzi---3d-).